# installing and running browsershots

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

I tried to install Brwoswershots (https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) and I did this exactly by following the instructions on github.

```
Installing NodeJS and npm via yum
Installing browswershoots via composer: composer require 
satie/browsershot

crated a file with 
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
$pathToImage="img/testasdf.png";
// an image will be saved
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
    ->setScreenshotType('jpeg', 100)
    ->save($pathToImage);
```

It is on http://textblob.com/browsershots.php and brings the error.

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught
> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException:
> The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node
> '/home/textblob/public_html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js'
> '{"url":"https:\/\/example.com",
>   "action":"screenshot",
>   "options": {
>       "type":"jpeg",
>       "path":"img\/testasdf.png",
>       "quality":100,
>       "args":[],
>       "viewport":{"width":800,"height":600}
>   }
> }'"
> failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory:
> /home/textblob/public_html
> ```

Output: ================ Error Output: ================

> ```
> /home/textblob/public_html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:5
> const getOutput = async (page, request) =>
> { ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
> at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
> at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
> at Module.runMa in /home/textblob/public_html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/Browsershot.php
> on line 565
> ```

Comment: Could the installed version of node be too old? https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/issues/188. (Browsershot requires node 7.6.0+). You can run `node -v` from the command line to see what version yum installed.

Comment: I have node version 8.0.0 installed so this should not be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by downgrading to boxshot v2, witch works without puppeteer and so its not a fix, but working for me.